# Compute the dimension of the quotient space $\mathfrak m_a/\mathfrak m_a^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, quotient-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism, co-tangent-space

> Let $\Omega$ be an open set of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathcal F(\Omega)$ be the unital commutative ring of infinitely differentiable real functions over $\Omega$. Given $a\in\Omega$, consider $\mathfrak m_a$ as the ideal given by:
> $$\mathfrak m_a=\big\{f\in\mathcal F(M)\text{ such that }f(a)=0\big\}$$
> I want prove to that $\dim (\mathfrak m_a/\mathfrak m_a^2)=n$.

For do so, I am going to suppose that $\Omega$ is open convex. By [Hadamard's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_lemma) each $f\in \mathfrak m_a$ can be written as:
$$f(x)=\sum_{\mu=1}^n f_\mu(x)(x^\mu-a^\mu),$$
where $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ are smooth real functions on $\Omega$ such that $f_\mu(a)=(\partial_\mu f)(a)$ for each $\mu$.

This implies that two functions $f,g\in\mathfrak m_a$ lies in the same equivalence class if and only if:
$$(\partial_\mu f)(a)=(\partial_\mu g)(a),\qquad\qquad(\star)$$
for each $1\leq\mu\leq n$

Now, denote $T_a^\star\mathbb R^n$ as the $\mathbb R$-vector space of linear maps $T_a\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$. Then using ($\star$) it is not difficult to show that:
$$\begin{array}{rcll}
\Phi: &\mathfrak m_a/\mathfrak m_a^2&\longrightarrow &T_a^\star\mathbb R^n\\
&f+\mathfrak m_a^2&\longrightarrow & \Phi(f+\mathfrak m_a^2)=d_af
\end{array}$$
is a linear isomorphism.

*My question is*: How can I show that $\Phi$ is in fact an isomorphism without supposing that $\Omega$ is convex?

Comment: Right you need convexity to define $\int_0^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a + t(x - a))\, dt$. The trick is to multiply $f$ with a function $\phi \in C^\infty_c$  which is constant $=1$ around $a$ so that $f\phi$ is smooth on $\Bbb{R}^n$. And obviously $f(1-\phi)$ is in $\mathfrak{m}_a^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!